# stop overwriting an xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

hey from my previous question..

ive managed to finally get it all working...

if i click submit.. a file is then created in xml format but if i enter new data it will overwrite the same file how do i stop this..

this is the code i am using

```
Protected Sub btnWriteXML_onClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try

            Dim enc As Encoding
            Dim objXMLTW As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("contact.xml"), enc)
            objXMLTW.WriteStartDocument()
            objXMLTW.WriteStartElement("Feedback Form")
```

how do i stop this from overwriting?

Comment: This creates contact.xml, and you don't want that overwritten. Fine. The next time they click the button, where do you want the data to go?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make the filename unique.  Perhaps adding a timestamp or a guid or writing logic to add a sequential number onto the filename?

Comment: how do i do this :s i just about got my head around asp and xml

when a file is saved it saved as contact.xml...

Comment: Server.MapPath(Guid.NewGuid().ToString + ".xml") for example